# Infinite steps in DataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` to load the images and pass them to my model as practice, but when I start training the output information showed that it couldn't go into next epoch and always stick to the first one, as shown below:

```
Epoch 1/10
   1658/Unknown - 388s 234ms/step - loss: 0.0501 - accuracy: 0.9872
```

And my code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img_size = 128
batch_size = 64
train_path = '/content/image'
data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, validation_split=0.1)

train_generator = data_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path, 
                             target_size=(img_size, img_size), 
                             color_mode='rgb',
                             batch_size=batch_size, 
                             shuffle=True, 
                             seed = 1, 
                             class_mode='categorical', 
                             subset='training'
                             )
validation_generator = data_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                             target_size=(img_size, img_size),
                             color_mode='rgb',
                             batch_size=batch_size,
                             shuffle=True,
                             seed = 1,
                             class_mode='categorical', 
                             subset='validation'
                             )

epochs=10
input_shape = (img_size,img_size,3)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
         tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
         tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=tf.nn.relu),
         tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-5)
model.compile(optimizer= optimiser, 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_generator, 
          epochs=epochs, 
          validation_data=validation_generator)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `model.fit` to `model.fit_generator`

Also, at the first epoch, it is ok to show `number/unknown` as it is figuring out how many steps it needs.

Comment: Thank for your reply. but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Then I am assuming your generator does not automatically infer `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` automatically, try to pass those to your `fit_generator` call as `model.fit_generator(...., steps_per_epoch=100, validation_steps=20)` for example.

Comment: That actually fix my problem, thank you. Although it is strange to me, because I didn't add those in Keras.

Comment: I’d also imagine it should not need, but glad your problem is solved